# Programmatic way to get host key fingerprint from AWS EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, rsa

Is there a programmatic way to get the host key fingerprint from AWS EC2.

I feel like this is so basic someone must have figured it out, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

> DESCRIPTION
> ssh-keyscan is a utility for gathering the public SSH host keys of a number of hosts.  It was designed to aid in building and verifying ssh_known_hosts files, the format of which is
> documented in sshd(8).  ssh-keyscan provides a minimal interface suitable for use by shell and perl scripts.

I think that you are looking for ssh-keyscan.